# Linked List Loop detection basic question

Tags: python, loops, data-structures, linked-list

So this is my code to detect loop. I have a doubt here. Why am I looking for current in dic instead of current.data in dic.? Its giving wrong answer if I store that value of the node alone. What happens when I store the value of the node instead of the Node. I am learning linked list, SO I am unable to grasp what happens when I store the Node itself and what happens when I store the value of Node alone.

```
def detectLoop(head):

    dic={}
    current=head
    flag=5
    while current is not None:
        if current in dic:
            flag=6
            break
        else:
            dic[current]=5
            current=current.next
    if flag==5:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Multiple nodes may have the same value, in this case storing and comparing all values from visited nodes would give false positives

Comment: Yes Sir. Thats right. But what happens when I store the node? Like how does it detect that its the same node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By comparing the node, you are checking if you are running across the same node object twice. By checking the value you are ignoring the situation where two nodes may share the same value, and thus, your method would report that there is a cycle when there really isn't. If there were no nodes with duplicate values, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Sir, That's my doubt. How come it identifies that its the same node object? Whats happening internally?

Comment: When you declare an object, really that variable is just storing a memory address that contains the data for that object. So interally, current is just equal to some random integer value like 2310481 that is an address in the computer. If you come across the same node, it has the same address, so you're just comparing the memory addresses and seeing that they are equal. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes Sir. I understood that. One more doubt.

Comment: When I declare, Self.head.next=Node(z), What I am telling is the next node of the head has the value of z?

Comment: And self.head.next is a separate node right now. right sir? Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes so, you set the .next of the head node to be equal to a new node that you just created in that line, with the value 'z'. So yes it's a totally new node you created since you called its constructor Node() to create the new object, and passed in z for the value parameter

Comment: Thank you Sir. Finally understood it. :)))

Answer (score 0):

If one has to detect the loop in the linked-list there is an easier and space-efficient method of 2 pointers
Take two references or pointers(fast and slow).
'fast' moves a pace of two, every time 'slow' moves one;
like fast = fast->next->next and slow = slow->next. In case both of them at any point meet again then there is a loop in the linked-list